# Bash/zsh tab autocomplete: Given initial command, ignore certain files in directory with autocomplete

Tags: bash, zsh, autocomplete

What I'm asking is a little bit specific, and might be a different than other autocomplete questions on Unix Stackexchange.

Suppose I have a directory that looks like this

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 hlin117 staff 1.1K Sep 19 13:05 doc.aux
-rw-r--r-- 1 hlin117 staff  26K Sep 19 13:05 doc.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 hlin117 staff 177K Sep 19 13:05 doc.pdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 hlin117 staff  13K Sep 19 13:01 doc.tex
```

It makes very little sense to try doing `vim doc.pdf`, and in the common case, I wouldn't be doing `vim doc.log` or `vim doc.aux`. Instead, I'd often do

```
vim doc.tex
```

Unfortunately, tab-autocomplete will suggest to me all 4 files instead of only `doc.tex`.

Is there a way where I could type `vim \t`, and this would ignore some certain files in my directory?

More generally, can I type command `X \t`, and write some setting where typing command `X` will ignore files in my directory?

FYI: I use zsh. Not sure whether bash and zsh will have similar solutions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In zsh, with the “new” completion system (i.e. if you have `compinit` in your `.zshrc`), use the [`file-patterns` style](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-file_002dpatterns_002c-completion-style).

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*:vim:*' file-patterns '^*.(aux|log|pdf):source-files' '*:all-files'
```

Files matching the pattern `*.(aux|log|pdf)` will only be completed on the `vim` command line if there would otherwise be no completion.

You can use a pattern for the command name, in particular `*` to match all commands except the ones that are matched explicitly.

Comment: Cool. Any way to do this with a whitelist instead of a blacklist?

Comment: @lindhe The `^` at the beginning of the pattern means “all except what follows”.

Comment: Oh, I thought it was the "start of line" character. Nice. And that would work similarly -- prioritizing .tex, but giving the others if there is no tex available?

Comment: I tried it, and with only `*.(tex)` as argument, it does not do any suggestions form me. With `*.tex` it only suggests .tex files. I want it to prioritize tex, not completely ignore the others. :/

Comment: OK, no, sorry. You are right. It works as intended. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Adding to this because I don't use zsh, and there is much more general option.

Just place in your `.bashrc` a line using the bash builtin command `complete`. For example:

```bsh
complete -f -X '*.@(aux|log|pdf)' -o plusdirs vim
```

where `-f` will complete filenames, `-X` filters out matching patterns from the possible choices with a glob string, and `-o plusdirs` will *afterward* add subdirectories to the list.